# Конструктор класса JS

Tags: javascript

```js
class Product {
    constructor(name, price) {
        this.productName = name || 'No Name';
        this.price = price || 0;
    }
    getInfo() {
        return `${this.productName} ${this.price}`;
    }
}
```

Мой вопрос: как мне создать объект класса Product с названием по умолчанию и заданной ценой? т.е. `const prod = new Product( 742);` мне нужно, чтобы конструктор понимал, что 742 - это price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
class Product {
    constructor(data) {
        this.productName = data.name || 'No Name';
        this.price = data.price || 0;
    }
    getInfo() {
        return `${this.productName} ${this.price}`;
    }
}

console.log((new Product({price:758})).getInfo());
```

Comment: Вопрос можно решить только передавая в конструктор объект? Если конструктор будет принимать args ничего не выйдет?

Comment: @MadFox представьте что вам нужно передать 10 параметров в конструктор, на мой взгляд проще и удобней воспользоваться объектом

Answer (score 1):

Думаю есть несколько способов это сделать

С помощью статических методов

```js
class Product {
  static fromPrice(price) {
    return new this(null, price);
  }

  constructor(name, price) {
    this.productName = name || 'No Name';
    this.price = price || 0;
  }

  getInfo() {
    return `${this.productName} ${this.price}`;
  }
}

console.log(Product.fromPrice(200).getInfo());
console.log(new Product('Main').getInfo());
```

Можно внутри конструктора определять по типу переменной, чем она является

```js
class Product {
  constructor() {
    this.productName = 'No Name';
    this.price = 0;
    
    // перебираем принятые аргументы
    for (const arg of arguments) {
      // проверяем тип аргумента
      switch (typeof arg) {
        // если тип является строкой
        case 'string': 
          // то это имя продукта
          this.productName = arg;
          break;
          
        // если число
        case 'number':
          // то цена
          this.price = arg;
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  getInfo() {
    return `${this.productName} ${this.price}`;
  }
}

console.log(new Product('Main').getInfo());
console.log(new Product(200).getInfo());
console.log(new Product(200, 'Main').getInfo());
```

Но как всегда остаётся один вопрос: зачем это нужно? Если это нужно, для того что бы ваш код никто и никогда не смог понять, тогда ладно. Если же вы хотите писать чисты и документируемый код, то предлагаю сделать так

```js
/**
 * Класс продукта
 * @property {string} productName Наименование продукта
 * @property {number} price Цена продукта
 */
class Product {

  /**
   * @param {string} [name='No Name'] Наименование продукта
   * @param {number} [price=0] Цена продукта
   */
  constructor(name, price) {
    this.productName = name || 'No Name';
    this.price = price || 0;
  }

  getInfo() {
    return `${this.productName} ${this.price}`;
  }
}

console.log(new Product(null, 200).getInfo());
console.log(new Product('Main').getInfo());
```